# Can I have a default class property?

Tags: delphi, properties, record

I'm trying to replace a explicitly declared `X: array[TypeX] of string` with a record and a default array property.
With some magic I can get it to work, but only if I have a dummy variable for my record.

I would like the following code to compile (everything up to `Fail` does). But I get a nonsensical error when I access the default property.

```
unit Test;
interface

type
  TSyntaxNodeType = (ntAddr,ntDeref);
  SyntaxNodeNames = record
  strict private
    class var FData: array[TSyntaxNodeType] of string;
    class function GetItem(const index: TSyntaxNodeType): string; static; inline;
    class constructor Init;
  public
    class property Items[const index: TSyntaxNodeType]: string read GetItem; default;
  end;

implementation
uses SysUtils, TypInfo;

{ TSyntaxNodeNames }

class function SyntaxNodeNames.GetItem(const index: TSyntaxNodeType): string;
begin
  Result:= FData[index];
end;

class constructor SyntaxNodeNames.Init;
var
  value: TSyntaxNodeType;
begin
  for value := Low(TSyntaxNodeType) to High(TSyntaxNodeType) do
    FData[value] := Copy(LowerCase(GetEnumName(TypeInfo(TSyntaxNodeType), Ord(value))), 3);
end;

function Fail: string;
begin
  Result:= SyntaxNodeNames[ntAddr];  //E2029 '(' expected but '[' found
end;

end.
```

It if I change everything around to non-class methods it works, but I'd like the record to not have an instance, only a type. I don't need the instance. 
I don't want a variable array, and I don't want to use writeable constants.

**Question**
Are default class properties supposed to work and is this a bug, or are default class properties forbidden somehow?

**UPDATE**
Here's the fix, but I don't like the fact that I need a dummy variable that never get instantiated.

```
type
  TSyntaxNodeNames = record
  strict private
    class var FData: array[TSyntaxNodeType] of string;
    function GetItem(const index: TSyntaxNodeType): string; inline;
    class constructor Init;
  public
    property Items[const index: TSyntaxNodeType]: string read GetItem; default;
  end;

var
  SyntaxNodeNames: TSyntaxNodeNames; //for some reason default does not work on class properties.

implementation
uses SysUtils, TypInfo;

{ TSyntaxNodeNames }

function TSyntaxNodeNames.GetItem(const index: TSyntaxNodeType): string;
begin
  Result:= FData[index];
end;

class constructor TSyntaxNodeNames.Init;
var
  value: TSyntaxNodeType;
begin
  for value := Low(TSyntaxNodeType) to High(TSyntaxNodeType) do
    FData[value] := Copy(LowerCase(GetEnumName(TypeInfo(TSyntaxNodeType), Ord(value))), 3);
end;

function DoesNotFail: string;
begin
  Result:= SyntaxNodeNames[ntAddr];  //Works as intended.
end;

end.
```

Comment: So, what is the question?

Comment: @Dsm, how to make the above code compile? Can I have a default class property?

Comment: @Victoria the question has changed since I asked ;-) The original had no question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Records are not classes, and if you don't want an instance, classes are the way to go.

This works as you want, and note that there are no instances:

```
unit Unit13;

interface

type
  TSyntaxNodeType = (ntAddr,ntDeref);

  SyntaxNodeNames = class
  strict private
    class var FData: array[TSyntaxNodeType] of string;
    class function GetItem(const index: TSyntaxNodeType): string; static; inline;
    class constructor Init;
  public
    class property Items[const index: TSyntaxNodeType]: string read GetItem; default;
  end;

implementation
uses SysUtils, TypInfo;

{ TSyntaxNodeNames }

class function SyntaxNodeNames.GetItem(const index: TSyntaxNodeType): string;
begin
  Result:= FData[index];
end;

class constructor SyntaxNodeNames.Init;
var
  value: TSyntaxNodeType;
begin
  for value := Low(TSyntaxNodeType) to High(TSyntaxNodeType) do
    FData[value] := Copy(LowerCase(GetEnumName(TypeInfo(TSyntaxNodeType), Ord(value))), 3);
end;

end.
```

I called this from the main form like this to test

```
procedure TForm10.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Panel1.Caption := SyntaxNodeNames[ntAddr];
end;
```

but I am sure that you have your own test methods.